# Android JobScheduler API

Tags: android, android-volley, android-jobscheduler

I am sending a request to a server using Volley in a JobService. My question is, since the service  runs on the main thread, should I create a seperate thread inside the service and call my Volley request there, or simple call the volley request? Here is some of my code.

```
public class JobService extends android.app.job.JobService {

static int count = 0;

@Override
public boolean onStartJob(final JobParameters jobParameters) {

    Log.d("Job Service", "onStartJob " + count);
    final SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(LOGIN_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d("Job Service", "onResponse");
            try {
                writeFileToCache(response);
                jobFinished(jobParameters, true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                jobFinished(jobParameters, true);
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d("Volley error job", error.toString());
            jobFinished(jobParameters, true);
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("regno", prefs.getString(REG_NO, ""));
            params.put("bdate", prefs.getString(DATE_OF_BIRTH, ""));
            return params;
        }
    };
    request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(12000, 0, 0f));
    queue.add(request);
    return true;
}

private void writeFileToCache(String response) throws IOException {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
        return;
    }
    File file = new File(getExternalCacheDir() + CACHE_FILE);
    FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(file);
    Log.d("Writing to cache job", response);
    fout.write(response.getBytes());
    fout.close();
}

@Override
public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters jobParameters) {
    Log.d("Job Service", "onStopJob");
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Volley itself is asynchronous; you should not need to fork your own thread here.

Comment: Ah, but the problem is, the onResponse and onErrorResponse function run on the main thread. So wouldn't that block the main thread there?

Comment: Yes, but unless Volley offers a way for you to provide your own `Looper` or `HandlerThread` or something, that's unavoidable. Personally, I don't use Volley much (I prefer OkHttp) and so I don't recall Volley's API. If you have significant work that needs to be done in `onResponse()` and/or `onErrorResponse()`, you may need to fork a thread in those callbacks or otherwise arrange for that work to be done off the main application thread.

Comment: All I'm doing is writing the response to a file, so I guess I should be okay.

Comment: Ideally, don't do disk I/O on the main application thread.